# Using multiple authentication methods in asp net framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I need to add Azure active directory authentication in our existing ASP.NET MVC website project, but i need to keed the form authentication method to.

i did all the steps in this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp

but for some reason is not redirecting to the AD login page, searching for a solution a see this: [IAuthenticationManager.Challenge not calling ExternalLoginCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023557/iauthenticationmanager-challenge-not-calling-externallogincallback)

setting the authentication mode to none and adding the tag  solve the problem with the redirecting, but remove the previous form authentication.

is there a way to use form Authentication and Azure AD  in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new application with Individual User Accounts.
- Install this package : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI
- services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer( Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); `services.AddDefaultIdentity() .AddEntityFrameworkStores(); services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => }).AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options)).AddCookie();
- Update  appsettings.json "AzureAd": { "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
- "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com", "TenantId": "xxxxxx-xxxxx-4f08-b544-b1eb456f228d",
- "ClientId": "xxxxx-xxxxx-4717-9821-e4f718fbece4", "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",

  "CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External" },

Read more about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp). & For Azure AD [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims).

Comment: but the original project is not in asp net core.
this look like a tutorial to use Azure ad only. How can i Use AD and forms authentication  with this?